# Word Wrap a Div, all on a single line

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

I have a string in a div:  Test: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

Using a the word_wrap CSS class found on Stack Overflow,

```
/* Source: http://snipplr.com/view/10979/css-cross-browser-word-wrap */
.wordwrap { 
white-space: pre-wrap;      /* CSS3 */   
white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Firefox */    
white-space: -pre-wrap;     /* Opera <7 */   
white-space: -o-pre-wrap;   /* Opera 7 */    
word-wrap: break-word;      /* IE */
}
```

it appears like this:

```
Test:
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

How can I wrap it so Test: and the A's are on the same line?

Comment: And what's the *"word_wrap CSS class found on Stack Overflow"*, are we supposed to know how that works ?

Comment: Please add more detail this question is asked in a poor fashion ... be more specific!

Comment: he's talking about the css3 word-wrap property (probably_

Comment: My apologies, fixed ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `&nbsp;` instead of a regular space:

```
Test:&nbsp;AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```